# how can I import csv file in flutter in 2.5?

Tags: flutter, dart

Kindly share the link of code or code and I m trying but I m not found anything good for importing CSV file

which library I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**so you can use Flutter csv library**
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

```
pickFile() async {
   FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
   if (result != null) {
     PlatformFile file = result.files.first;

     final input = new File(file.path).openRead();
     final fields = await input
         .transform(utf8.decoder)
         .transform(new CsvToListConverter())
         .toList();

     print(fields);
   }
 }
```