# CSV File not selecting and uploading in flutter

Tags: flutter, csv, file, dart, mobile-development

i am uploading CSV file in flutter using FilePicker but when i open my Gallery using file picker csv file not selectable and hence i am unable to upload CSV file with csv extension. How can i resolve this issue?

```
 result = await  FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                            type: FileType.custom,
                             allowedExtensions: ['csv']

                          );

                          if(result == null) return;



                          ///Open Single File
                          file = result!.files.first;

                          setState((){});
```

**this is my code to upload CSV File.**

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69436103/how-can-i-import-csv-file-in-flutter-in-2-5

Comment: As alternative solution is that you can remove allowedExtensions option and use FileType.any so that any file can be picked.